# Is there a function to get counts in multiple columns from multiple datasets?

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have 2 columns of postal codes. One represents my orders, and the other represents reported issues with these orders, both are in separate data sets.

I have a Postal Code column in my orders dataset:

```
B0E1H0
B3M0G4
B3K6R6
B3L1J7
B0E1H0
B3K3M2
B3K2Z8
B0E1H0
B3K6R6
B0E1H0
```

I have a postal code column in my reported issues dataset:

```
B3K6R6
B3K6R6
B0E1H0
B0E1H0
B3L1J7
```

I would like to end up with a data frame that gives me a list of unique postal codes, the count of volume, the count of issue, and the proportion of issues for each postal code, so something like this:

```
Postal code, Volume, Issues, Issue %
BOE1H0, 4, 2, 50%
B3K2Z8, 1, 0, 0%
B3K3M2, 1, 0, 0%
B3K6R6, 2, 2, 100%
B3L1J7, 1, 1, 100%
B3M0G4, 1, 0, 0%
```

I was able to get the 1st 2 rows by doing something like this:

```
    orders <- read.csv("G:\\My Drive\\R\\R Data\\Stuff\\Text File\\Orders.csv", header = TRUE)
pcvec <- as.vector(orders["Postal.Code"])
unipc <- unique(pcvec,incomparables = F)
unipcvec <- as.vector(unipc)
pccount <- count(orders, "Postal.Code")
nrow(unipc)
x <- data.frame(pccount)
x <- rename(x, c("freq" = "Volume"))
x

    Postal.Code Volume
1        B0C1H0      1
2        B0E1B0      3
3        B0E1H0      7
4        B0E1L0      1
5        B0E1N0      1
6        B0E1P0      1
7        B0E1V0      1
8        B0E1W0      1
9        B0E2K0      1
```

I have about 5000 rows in my volume dataset about 300 in my issues dataset, is possible to do this easily?

Apologies if I don’t have the proper terminology, please let me know if I can clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, `setDT(df2)`), get the number of rows (`.N`) by 'V1', do a join `on` the 'V1', then get the percentage by dividing the non-common columns, while assigning the `NA` to 0

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(df1)[, .N, V1][setDT(df2)[, .N, V1], 
    Issues := i.N, on = .(V1)][, Issue_perc:= Issues/N * 100][is.na(Issues), 
     c('Issues', 'Issue_perc') := 0], 'N', 'Volume')[]
#       V1 Volume Issues Issue_perc
#1: B0E1H0      4      2         50
#2: B3M0G4      1      0          0
#3: B3K6R6      2      2        100
#4: B3L1J7      1      1        100
#5: B3K3M2      1      0          0
#6: B3K2Z8      1      0          0
```

---

Or another option with `dcast`

```
dcast(rbindlist(list(df1, df2), idcol = 'grp')[, .N, .(grp, V1)],
   V1 ~ c("Volume", "Issues")[grp], value.var = "N", fill = 0)[, 
      Issue_perc := Issues/Volume * 100][]
#         V1 Issues Volume Issue_perc
#1: B0E1H0      2      4         50
#2: B3K2Z8      0      1          0
#3: B3K3M2      0      1          0
#4: B3K6R6      2      2        100
#5: B3L1J7      1      1        100
#6: B3M0G4      0      1          0
```

---

Or using `base R`, we create a `union` of elements in the 'V1' column from both datasets, then convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as the 'lvls', get the `table`, do a `merge` and `transform` to create the 'Issue_perc' column

```
lvls <- union(df1$V1, df2$V1)
transform(merge(as.data.frame(table(factor(df1$V1, levels = lvls))), 
   as.data.frame(table(factor(df2$V1, levels = lvls))), by = 'Var1'), 
    Issue_perc = Freq.y/Freq.x * 100)
#     Var1 Freq.x Freq.y Issue_perc
#1 B0E1H0      4      2         50
#2 B3K2Z8      1      0          0
#3 B3K3M2      1      0          0
#4 B3K6R6      2      2        100
#5 B3L1J7      1      1        100
#6 B3M0G4      1      0          0
```

---

or an option with `tidyverse`, we get the datasets into a `list`, `map` through the `list`, convert the 'V1' to `factor` with `levels` specified as earlier, `reduce` the `list` to a single data.frame by doing an `inner_join`, then create the percentage column with `mutate`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(df1, df2) %>% 
    map(~ .x %>% 
             mutate(V1 = factor(V1, levels = lvls)) %>% 
             count(V1,  .drop = FALSE)) %>%
             reduce(inner_join, by = 'V1') %>% 
             mutate(Issue_perc = n.y/n.x * 100) %>% 
             rename_at(vars(matches('n\\.')), ~ c("Volume", "Issues"))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  V1     Volume Issues Issue_perc
#  <fct>   <int>  <int>      <dbl>
#1 B0E1H0      4      2         50
#2 B3M0G4      1      0          0
#3 B3K6R6      2      2        100
#4 B3L1J7      1      1        100
#5 B3K3M2      1      0          0
#6 B3K2Z8      1      0          0
```

---

Or a slightly different option is to place the datasets in a `list`, then bind them with a grouping column, `count`  to get the frequency, `spread` to 'wide' format and then create the new 'perc' column

```
list(df1, df2) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>%
    count(grp, V1) %>% 
    mutate(grp = c("Volume", "Issues")[as.integer(grp)]) %>% 
    spread(grp, n, fill = 0) %>% 
    mutate(Issue_perc = Issues/Volume * 100)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  V1     Issues Volume Issue_perc
#  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 B0E1H0      2      4         50
#2 B3K2Z8      0      1          0
#3 B3K3M2      0      1          0
#4 B3K6R6      2      2        100
#5 B3L1J7      1      1        100
#6 B3M0G4      0      1          0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("B0E1H0", "B3M0G4", "B3K6R6", "B3L1J7", 
"B0E1H0", "B3K3M2", "B3K2Z8", "B0E1H0", "B3K6R6", "B0E1H0")), row.names 
= c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("B3K6R6", "B3K6R6", "B0E1H0", "B0E1H0", 
"B3L1J7")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

One way with `dplyr` assuming the two dataframes are called `df1` and `df2` and the columns is called `V1` in both the dataset. We `count` the frequency of each postal code in both the dataframes and join them on `V1` column, replace the non-matching columns with 0 and calculate the issue percentage by dividing `Issues` by `Volume`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  count(V1) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% count(V1), by = "V1") %>%
  rename_all(~c("Postal_Code", "Volume", "Issues")) %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(list(Issues = 0)) %>%
  mutate(Issue_perc = Issues/Volume * 100)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Postal_Code Volume Issues Issue_perc
#  <chr>        <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 B0E1H0           4      2         50
#2 B3K2Z8           1      0          0
#3 B3K3M2           1      0          0
#4 B3K6R6           2      2        100
#5 B3L1J7           1      1        100
#6 B3M0G4           1      0          0
```

---

Using `dplyr` it is easy to perform such operation with chaining. Otherwise, we can also do the same operations using only base R

```
temp_df <- merge(stack(table(df1)), stack(table(df2)), by = "ind", all.x = TRUE)
temp_df$values.y[is.na(temp_df$values.y)] <- 0
temp_df$Issue_perc <- temp_df$values.y/temp_df$values.x * 100
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("B0E1H0", "B3M0G4", "B3K6R6", "B3L1J7", 
"B0E1H0", "B3K3M2", "B3K2Z8", "B0E1H0", "B3K6R6", "B0E1H0")), row.names 
= c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("B3K6R6", "B3K6R6", "B0E1H0", "B0E1H0", 
"B3L1J7")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```